# Not exists operator error on multiple tables selection

Tags: sql, oracle, not-exists

This selection works great with NOT IN, but with NOT EXISTS it returns an error:
    SQL Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
    00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"

Does NOT EXISTS works  other way?

```
select COMPANY.TITLE_COMPANY
from COMPANY 
outer join LOCATION on (LOCATION.NAME_LOC = COMPANY.NAME_LOC)
where  COMPANY.NUM_COMPANY  not exists (select NUM_COMPANY from COMPANY_SUC)
;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would all help.  Your query makes no sense.

Comment: that's return from NOT IN: 
TITLE_COMPANY                     
------------------------------
PADMEDIA
CLEANHOUSE
At least NOT EXISTS, must return no rows selected, instead of error

Comment: With NOT EXISTS, I want to select company names from table COMPANY, that are not exist  table COMPANY_SUC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong and it's easy to spot why. Mind that a `where not exists` clause is used to subtract one set of data from another set:

```
select
   ename
from
   emp
where NOT EXISTS
   (select
      null
   from
      dependents
   where
      emp.empno = dependents.empno
   and ...
   );
```

But you're trying to relate it to a specific field in the base query, which is wrong, it is not exactly as NOT IN, which compares data in a column to a subquery result.

Don't try to replace it with one another.

Comment: I'm just baffled at how a query using `emp` and `dependents` is the answer to this question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, you were asking for expected outcome and samle data when it was a matter of syntax. On that I cannot help you with